# UIImageView not updating image when displayed in a UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am new to Xcode and objective C so the problem I have hit may be a simple one but I haven't been able to find an answer yet so thanks for any help you can give.

I am trying to write a simple app that takes a picture from the camera and displays it in a `UIImageView`. This all works fine if the `UIImageView` control is just placed in the `UIView` control (using the interface builder). The code I use to set the image to the control is

```
[self.imageViewOSFCorner setImage:image];
```

However I need to display several images an wanted the user to be able to scroll up and down the page. So I created a `UIScrollView` in the interface builder that is the size I need and placed all the controls in that. Then in the `viewDidLoad` method I placed the following code to display the `UIScrollView`

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

This works in that you can now scroll the page and see all of the `UIImageView` controls, and when I press the button it launches the camera, but now after taking the picture it doesn't display the image into the `UIImageView`. If I take the `UIScrollView` away it works again (but obviously doesn't scroll) - I am guessing I am doing something silly, is there a function I need to call to update the `UIScrollView`?

As an aside I originally tried to use the code

```
self.imageViewOSFCorner.image = image;
```

to display the image but this wouldn't display the image and had to use

```
[self.imageViewOSFCorner setImage:image];
```

can someone tell me why the first method didn't work?

Thanks

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is working now, I must have done something stupid when creating the controls into the `UIScrollView` since I have started from scratch again in the interface builder and now it all works.

Answer (score 0):

May be useful：
 self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width*num,view.frame.size.hight );
num is your number of all image

Comment: Didn't need to do this, I am guessing since I created the `UIScrollView` in the interface builder doesn't it automatically set the frame size based on the size of the control?